# ComboBox does not update SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am dynamically creating a combo box control which is added to a view at runtime.

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.Height = 21;
comboBox.Width = 75;
var margin = comboBox.Margin;
margin.Right += 5;
comboBox.Margin = margin;
comboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding($"SearchDescriptor.SelectedFilter.FilterControls[{InputPosition}].Conditions"));
comboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "ConditionOperator";
comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
comboBox.SetBinding(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding($"SearchDescriptor.SelectedFilter.FilterControls[{InputPosition}].SelectedCondition"));
Grid.SetColumn(comboBox, 1);
return comboBox;
```

This is the code that generates the combo box control. The control itself gets placed on a view that has DataContext set to some view model with property named

```
SearchDescriptor
```

This property has a selected filter property that holds a collection of control object. These control object are responsible for generating the control and setting up the binding.

Let me start of by saying that initially the bindings work but once I start selecting options from combo box, it doesn't update the property it is bound to.
This is weird since the path is obviously correct otherwise it wouldn't be initially binding the properties.

I have looked through all the questions that are remotely connected to this issue and have tried all of things but to no avail.

The SelectedItem is bound to a property named SelectedCondition that is of type Condition and the class looks like this:

```
public struct Condition
{
    public ConditionOperator ConditionOperator { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public Condition(ConditionOperator conditionOperator, string text)
    {
        ConditionOperator = conditionOperator;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
The class that implements the property SelectedCondition

```
public class SearchDescriptorFilterControl
{
    private SearchDescriptorFilter m_filter;
    private IEnumerable<ConditionOperator> m_choosableConditions;
    private object m_value;

    public SearchDescriptorFilter Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return m_filter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_filter != null)
                throw new Exception("Filter can be set only once.");
            m_filter = value;
        }
    }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public double? LabelWidth { get; set; }

    public HorizontalAlignment LabelContentAlignment { get; set; } = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    public double Width { get; set; } = 100;

    public string ConditionExpression { get; set; }

    public FilterType Type { get; set; }

    private Condition m_conditionOperator;
    public Condition SelectedCondition
    {
        get
        {
            return m_conditionOperator;
        }
        set
        {
            m_conditionOperator = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ConditionOperator> ChoosableConditions
    {
        get
        {
            return m_choosableConditions;
        }
        set
        {
            var mappings = new Dictionary<ConditionOperator, string>()
            {
                [ConditionOperator.Contains] = "Contains",
                [ConditionOperator.EndsWith] = "Ends with",
                [ConditionOperator.Equals] = "Equals",
                [ConditionOperator.Greater] = "Greater",
                [ConditionOperator.GreaterOrEqual] = "Greater or equal",
                [ConditionOperator.Less] = "Less",
                [ConditionOperator.LessOrEqual] = "Less or equal",
                [ConditionOperator.StartsWith] = "Starts with"
            };
            m_choosableConditions = value;
            if (value != null && value.Any())
            {
                //Conditions = new Condition[value.Count()];
                //int i = 0;
                foreach (var condition in value)
                {
                    Conditions.Add(new Condition(condition, mappings[condition]));
                    //Conditions[i] = new Condition(condition, mappings[condition]);
                    //i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Condition> Conditions { get; private set; } = new List<Condition>();

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return m_value;
        }
        set
        {
            m_value = value;
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldShowOperatorsComboBox
    {
        get
        {
            return ChoosableConditions != null && ChoosableConditions.Any();
        }
    }

    private int InputPosition
    {
        get
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var filterControl in Filter.FilterControls)
            {
                if (filterControl == this)
                    return i;
                i++;
            }
            throw new Exception($"Input cannot be found for filter {Filter.Name} and control {Label}.");
        }
    }

    public SearchDescriptorFilterControl() { }

    private Grid GetGrid()
    {
        var grid = new Grid();

        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        if (ShouldShowOperatorsComboBox)
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

        return grid;
    }

    private Label GetLabel()
    {
        var label = new Label();

        label.Content = Label;
        if (LabelWidth.HasValue)
            label.Width = LabelWidth.Value;
        else
        {
            var margin = label.Margin;
            margin.Right += 5;
            label.Margin = margin;
        }
        label.HorizontalContentAlignment = LabelContentAlignment;
        Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);

        return label;
    }

    private ComboBox GetConditionsComboBox()
    {
        var comboBox = new ComboBox();

        comboBox.Height = 21;
        comboBox.Width = 75;
        var margin = comboBox.Margin;
        margin.Right += 5;
        comboBox.Margin = margin;
        comboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding($"SearchDescriptor.SelectedFilter.FilterControls[{InputPosition}].Conditions"));
        comboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
        comboBox.SelectedValuePath = nameof(Condition.ConditionOperator);
        comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = nameof(Condition.Text);
        comboBox.SetBinding(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding($"SearchDescriptor.SelectedFilter.FilterControls[{InputPosition}].SelectedCondition")
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        });
        Grid.SetColumn(comboBox, 1);

        return comboBox;
    }

    private TextBox GetTextInput()
    {
        var input = new TextBox();

        input.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding($"SearchDescriptor.SelectedFilter.FilterControls[{InputPosition}].Value") { Delay = 1000, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

        return input;
    }

    private DatePicker GetDateInput()
    {
        var input = new DatePicker();

        input.SetBinding(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, new Binding($"SearchDescriptor.SelectedFilter.FilterControls[{InputPosition}].Value") { Delay = 1000, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

        return input;
    }

    public Grid GetInputFilter()
    {
        var grid = GetGrid();
        grid.Children.Add(GetLabel());

        //At the moment the column for filter input is 1 - immediately after the label.
        var inputColumn = 1;

        // If the collection has any element that means we must supply
        // condition combo box so the user can choose a condition operator.
        // For that we create another column.
        if (ShouldShowOperatorsComboBox)
        {
            var comboBox = GetConditionsComboBox();
            grid.Children.Add(comboBox);

            //Combo box comes after the label which means
            //input filter comes after the combo box so we
            //will increment the inputColumn value by 1.
            inputColumn++;
        }

        //Filter input.
        FrameworkElement inputFilter;
        if (Type == FilterType.Date)
            inputFilter = GetDateInput();
        else
            inputFilter = GetTextInput();
        inputFilter.Width = Width;

        Grid.SetColumn(inputFilter, inputColumn);
        grid.Children.Add(inputFilter);

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: DId you set the Binding Mode twoWay? Did you check that all you binded objects are firering a PropertyChangedEvent?

Comment: Mode = TwoWay is not needed since I am not going the other way. I am only interested in View updating my model. Not the other way around.

Comment: @mm8 It is at the bottom of my question. Just replace struct with class.

Comment: That's certainly not the class with the SelectedCondition and Conditions property that you bind to...

Comment: @mm8 I have updated the question. Now that the class is out there I would also like to point to one strange thing that buffels me even more. The property Value which is binded to a input works correctly so I think the problem in the end is with ComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `SelectedValuePath` when you bind to the `SelectedItem` property. Also, since it seems you create the `ComboBox` in the same class where the source properties are defined, you might as well specify the `Source` of the bindings like this:

```
private ComboBox GetConditionsComboBox()
{
    var comboBox = new ComboBox();

    comboBox.Height = 21;
    comboBox.Width = 75;
    var margin = comboBox.Margin;
    margin.Right += 5;
    comboBox.Margin = margin;
    comboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Conditions") { Source = this });
    comboBox.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
    comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = nameof(Condition.Text);
    comboBox.SetBinding(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("SelectedCondition")
    {
        Source = this,
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    });
    Grid.SetColumn(comboBox, 1);

    return comboBox;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that setting the Source in the binding to this did the trick.